# JSON.NET serialization of type derived from List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

We're switching our cache system over from a binary serializer (the one AppFabric uses) to a JSON serializer (For use with Redis) and I'm running into some incompatibilities with a few object types.  The general idea is the same, we have a class that looks something like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class ActivityMeasurementIndexes : List<ActivityMeasurementIndex>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime lastDbRead { get; set; }

    public ActivityMeasurementIndexes()
    {
        lastDbRead = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

The binary serializer will serialize and deserialize the object just fine.  However, when I try to serialize the object with JSON.NET, I get:

```
var testObject = new ActivityMeasurementIndexes { Id = 5 };
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testObject);
"[]"
```

So, JSON.NET is basically serializing the base `List<T>` but the properties in the derived type are getting lost.  I could probably refactor this class so it has a `public List<ActivityMeasurementIndex> Items { get; set }` instead, but we have quite a few of these classes and tons of code that would also have to be refactored.

Is there a good approach to handle this?  I don't really care *how* the JSON looks as long as I can serialize and deserialize the base list as well as the properties on the class.  I'm guessing I would need to write some sort of custom converter, or maybe there's something JSON.NET can do out of the box to help me out.  Any hints for stuff to read up on would be great!